# Can't Run Roo Command!

Tags: spring-roo

I am trying to run command "Security SetUp" from roo shell that is embedded in SpringSource Tool Suite. But keep getting following...

Command 'security setup' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)

Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Roo will print this type of message (a command was found but is not currently available) when the command has dependencies which has not been satisfied yet.

According to the Roo manual and [this report](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-506) you have to set up the web layer (with creating at least one controller) before adding security.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that. Is there a way (documentation available) which talks about what are command dependencies?

Comment: I do not know such documentation. This particular dependency is mentioned in the 2.10 chapter of the Roo manual (Securing the application chapter of the tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the project in the Roo console. That worked for me for a similar problem.